# MapServer offset spacing with point pattern

Tags: mapserver

I'm trying to add some point pattern like this :

[image: dashing on QGIS]

On MapServer. The best I achieved yet is this:

[image: dashing on MapServer]

Using

```
STYLE
  SYMBOL 'circle'
  SIZE 7
  COLOR 9 13 248
END
```

I did not find any indication on how set an offset between my circles.

Comment: Use a pixmap symbol with two points in diagonal positions. Find "Polygon fills with symbols of TYPE pixmap" from https://www.mapserver.org/mapfile/symbology/construction.html.

Comment: [GAP](https://mapserver.org/mapfile/style.html#index-7)?